# relative translation matrix between two AR markers

Tags: math, graphics, augmented-reality, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to write a simple AR app at the moment, specifically I am trying to compute the translation between two square markers similar to how they are doing it on this website at the bottom: [Artoolkit](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/documentation/tutorialcamera.htm)

The markers I am using are both the same size (100mm x 100mm) and my image has no camera distortion (I am using a test image at the moment).

Currently my process is following these steps:

1. Detect markers from image and extract out corners.
2. Run Co-planar POSIT given the marker corners.
3. Given 2 marker transformations (A and B), compute Inverse(A) * B
4. Decompose to grab marker B's x,y, and z translation relative to marker A.

The problem is my results seem totally off. Below is a screen of the program:

[image: markers_reper_off]

The orange squares represent where the corners are, I have checked these and they are correct.

I have overlain the axes using XNA. 
I am using AForge.net for the coplanar POSIT.
Image is 640x480.
Coplanar posit knows the markers are 100mm and the focal length is set to 640.

The exact code I am running to do this in c#:

```
    private void computePOSIT()
    {

        matrixes.Clear();
        AForge.Math.Matrix3x3 matrix;
        AForge.Math.Vector3 trans;
        foreach (Marker m in markers)
        {

            AForge.Point[] points = new AForge.Point[4]; 

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                points[i] = 
                    new AForge.Point(m.corners[i].X-320 ,240 - m.corners[i].Y);
            }

            posit.EstimatePose(points, out matrix, out trans);

            float yaw, pitch, roll;

            matrix.ExtractYawPitchRoll(out yaw, out pitch, out roll);

            Matrix rotation = 
                Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(-yaw, -pitch, roll);

            Matrix translation = 
                Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(trans.X, trans.Y, -trans.Z));

            Matrix complete = rotation * translation;
            List<Matrix> all = new List<Matrix>();
            all.Add(rotation);
            all.Add(translation);
            all.Add(complete);
            matrixes.Add(all);

        }

        Matrix res = Matrix.Invert(matrixes[0][4]) * matrixes[1][5];
        Vector3 scaleR;
        Vector3 translationR;
        Quaternion rotationR;
        res.Decompose(out scaleR, out rotationR, out translationR);

    }
```

Resulting matrix shows that:

TranslationR: X:-402.2295 Y:191.7873 Z:-135.3166}
RotationR: {X:0.007288148 Y:-0.4478231 Z:-0.5093549 W:0.734819}
scaleR: 1,1,1

Update: I have fixed the POSIT problem and the axes align correctly now, however the translation issue still exists. Is my maths correct to work out the relative translation?

Comment: it seems like wrong perspective correction resulting in invalid corner position in real world which lead to the offset and may be even slight orientation distortion of the input points into your algorithm